# Using Cypress to check if an item is in a list. IF yes, click to open it, ELSE create it

Tags: cypress

I am trying to solve a problem within Cypress.  Check to see if a list has any entries.  IF it does, click on any of them (does't matter which one) to open the item, ELSE, create an entry`

```
If (cy.get(#SigList).should(should('not.contain', 'No data available in table')) {
    cy.get(#SigList).contains(/.*/).click({force: true})
} else {
    cy.log(' Nothing in the list')
}
```

`
This does not work.  If there is an entry it does not open it.  If there is nothing in the list it just fails.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No error, just nothing happens if there is something in the list or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list has multiple items, then you can use length and perform actions.

```
cy.get(#SigList).then((ele) => {

  if (ele.length === 0)
    cy.log('Nothing in the list')

  else
    //Click on the first item
    ele.eq(0).click()
})
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer.  This does not work.  If there is something in the list, it is not clicked, opened.  If there is nothing in the list, nothing is logged.  Always passes regardless if something is in the list or not.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the HTML for list with elements?